# Retrieve latest exam rows for each student

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Student with Registraion No="A1" appeared in 1st year in exam "1" and then appeared in exam "2"

I want a query that return the sum of Tmarks for "A1" of exam "2"

```
select * from table1
```

```
   1|   A1| istYear | 100 |
   1|   A1| istYear | 100 |
   1|   A1| istYear | 50  |
 # 1|   A1| 2ndYear | 100 |
 # 1|   A1| 2ndYear | 100 |
 # 2|   A1| istYear | 100 |
 # 2|   A1| istYear | 100 |
 # 2|   A1| istYear | 50  |
```

```
    select Regno, iYr, sYr
    from 
        (select 
             Regno,
             sum(case year1 when 'istYear' then tmarks end) as iyr, 
             sum(case year1 when '2ndYear' then tmarks end)  as syr
         from 
             Table1 
         group by 
             regno) as p1
```

```
    # Regno  iYr    sYr
    ---------------------
      A1    | 500|  200
   ---------------------
```

I want a query that returns:

```
# Regno  iYr    sYr
 ---------------------
  A1    | 250  |  200
  ----------------------
```

The student with Registration No. "A1" appeared in Exam Number 1 and 2 in "Ist year".

I want a query that make the sum of Tmarks for student with Registration No "A1" that appear in the last Exam ie Exam 2.

[image]

Comment: SQL is all well and good, but please remember to  tag the flavour (RDBMS) as they are different and will help your question be found by the right people, e.g.; MySQL, T-SQL, PostgreSQL

Comment: @CanO'Spam In Headline you can find the word sql-server

Comment: To answer the *title's* question: Last based on what criteria? There's no implied order in a table unless you add an `ORDER BY` clause. Once you decide on the criteria, you can limit the results using product-specific syntax, eg `SELECT TOP 1 * From TheTable ORDER BY whatever Desc` in SQL Server, `SELECT * ... LIMIT 1;` in MySQL

Comment: Shouldn't `Exam` (based on your your *image*) be in your `GROUP BY` too or should not be filtering to where the value of `Exam` has a value of `1` in your derived table?

Answer (score 3):

You want the rows with the greatest exam number per regno and year. You get these with `DENSE_RANK` giving the newest rows rank #1.

```
with newest as
(
  select top(1) with ties *
  from table1
  order by dense_rank() over (partition by regno, year1 order by exam desc)
)
select 
  regno,
  sum(case year1 when 'istYear' then tmarks end) as iyr, 
  sum(case year1 when '2ndYear' then tmarks end) as syr
from newest
group by regno
order by regno;
```

`TOP (1) WITH TIES` is propriatary to SQL Server. In standard SQL this is `FETCH FIRST ROW WITH TIES`.

You can instead find the newest rows in two steps, as suggested by Panagiotis Kanavos, as follows:

```
with ranked as
(
  select
    table1.*,
    dense_rank() over (partition by regno, year1 order by exam desc) as rnk
  from table1
)
, newest as
(
  select *
  from ranked
  where rnk = 1
)
select ...
from newest ...
```

Comment: This is almost certainly homework. I suspect the OP will be confused by the way `TOP (1) WITH TIES` is used here and won't be able to explain it. It's probably easier to explain if `dense_rank() over (partition by regno, year1 order by exam desc)` is used and then the rank is filtered

Comment: Agree with @PanagiotisKanavos, i feel that top 1 with ties is more of a party trick for more advanced users